# Use the Material Theme colors on custom Angular components

Tags: angular, angular-material

I think I must be missing something fundamental here (its been a long day). I have an Angular app set up using a material theme (indigo-pink) which works fine on the material components.
I am now setting up a custom component and I'd just like to use the colors from the material theme to style it up a bit. This seems like it should be simple but everything I read pushes me back to the docs and creating mixins and defining themes.
Do I have to define a theme? I just want to use the `primary` theme color on my custom component.

I guess I'm maybe misunderstanding something about the nature of themes but is there a simple way to do this?

Cheers all

Comment: Basically yes, yes you do https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components

Comment: @AndrewAllen Fair enough, I had been through that page but thought it seemed like overkill to just use a colour from a theme that I had already installed. If thats the way it has to be done then that is the way I shall do it. Cheers

Comment: You've installed it but when you import the prebuilt theme you're effectively defining the mixins, just not directly e.g. https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.scss

Comment: @AndrewAllen Yeah, I think I was making some incorrect assumptions. I need to sit down and binge the docs I think, rather than just treating like a standard stylesheet